# What is texture(iChannel0,vec2) equivalence in Core Image Kernel Language?

Tags: ios, shader, core-image, ciimage, cikernel

```
float r = texture(iChannel3, view1).r;
float g = texture(iChannel3, view2).g;
float b = texture(iChannel3, view3).b;

fragColor = vec4(r, g, b, 1.);
```

How Can I Convert this shader syntax in Core Image Kernel Language?

Comment: You seem to be missing some context. For instance, what is `iChannel3`? More, why is there a `view1`, `view2`, and `view3`? What *exactly* are you trying to do? CoreImage should always be "approached" on a pixel-by-pixel basis (most likely the concept of textures/shaders really do not cleanly apply).

Comment: @dfd Actually i am trying to convert this ( https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4scBRH ) shader file into CIKernel Language and stuck at the finale.